# Having issues deploying spring boot app to tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I'm deploying to tomcat 7.0.52 but keep running into this error.
I feel like it's most liekly something to do with my pom and server class.

```
    Feb 09, 2018 5:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/sample-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/sample-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/sample-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/sample-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/sample-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-7.0.52.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/sample-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.16.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/sample-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.23.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/sample-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.27.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
Feb 09, 2018 5:02:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sample-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager;
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.<clinit>(WsWebSocketContainer.java:78)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

Feb 09, 2018 5:02:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/sample-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sample-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my pom.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
            <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <relativePath>../parent</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>sample-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>sample-webapp</name>
    <description>Next Gen Webapp</description>
    <properties>
            <log4j.configuration>log4j.xml</log4j.configuration>
            <tiles.version>3.0.3</tiles.version>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <tomcat.version>7.0.52</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                    <version>${tomcat.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            </plugin>
                            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId> <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                                    <version>9.1.2.v20140210</version> </plugin> -->
                            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
                                    <version>2.4</version> <configuration> <systemProperties> <property> <name>log4j.configuration</name> 
                                    <value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</value> </property> </systemProperties> <packagingExcludes 
                                    /> </configuration> <executions> <execution> <id>war</id> <phase>package</phase> 
                                    <goals> <goal>war</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> </plugin> -->
                            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                            <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                                    <configuration>
                                            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                                                    <pluginExecutions>
                                                            <pluginExecution>
                                                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                                                            <groupId>
                                                                                    org.apache.maven.plugins
                                                                            </groupId>
                                                                            <artifactId>
                                                                                    maven-compiler-plugin
                                                                            </artifactId>
                                                                            <configuration>
                                                                                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                                                                            </configuration>
                                                                            <versionRange>
                                                                                    [3.1,)
                                                                            </versionRange>
                                                                            <goals>
                                                                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                                                            </goals>
                                                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                                                    <action>
                                                                            <ignore></ignore>
                                                                    </action>
                                                            </pluginExecution>
                                                    </pluginExecutions>
                                            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                                    </configuration>
                            </plugin>
                    </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

And my server config

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.test.sample"})
public class Server extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Server.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Server.class, args);     
}
}
```

I also nuked my .m2 folder and that didn't work either. I also tried adding provided to tomcat-embed-core and tomcat-embed-el but that didn't work either

**UPDATE**: It was a maven clean thing. That and I had to remove the tomcat dependencies to get it all working.  Even tho i tried thta before, it didn't work cus I didn't run mvn clean.

Although now i'm getting error creating bean name 'defaultMethodEndpointAdapter'....

Comment: For starters - remove the tomcat-embed and embed-el deps and remove the "provided" from Spring's tomcat-starter declaration. Can you check in your dependency graph if you have the artifact <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId> and if no try to add it to your pom with the right version.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I just had to remove the tomcat dependencies then do mvn clean and it worked. But now I'm getting error creating bean with name 'defaultMEthodEndpointAdapter' :\

Comment: can you provide the new error stacktrace?

Comment: @hovanessyan yes. I opened a ticket for it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48716587/4674389